# Split a String based on regex

Tags: java, regex

I have a string that needs to be split based on the occurrence of a ","(comma), but need to ignore any occurrence of it that comes within a pair of parentheses.
For example, `B2B,(A2C,AMM),(BNC,1NF),(106,A01),AAA,AX3`
Should be split into

```
B2B,
(A2C,AMM),
(BNC,1NF),
(106,A01),
AAA,
AX3
```

Comment: Did you need the comma `,` after `B2B`?

Comment: No. that was just to demonstrate how it should be split.

Comment: Maybe you could check csv parsers. That's exactly what they do, except that they deal with quotes instead of parentheses.

Comment: str.split("\\([^)]*\\)|[^,()]+"); returns all ","

Comment: What about the string "B2B,((A2C,AMM),CCC),(ABC,CBA),AAA"? Do you need to deal with something like this (ie, balanced parenthesis)? If so, forget about regexes, it is impossible (and I really mean *impossible*, not simply *extremely hard*).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**FOR NON NESTED**

```
,(?![^\(]*\))
```

**FOR NESTED**(parenthesis inside parenthesis)

```
(?<!\([^\)]*),(?![^\(]*\))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try below:

```
var str = 'B2B,(A2C,AMM),(BNC,1NF),(106,A01),AAA,AX3';
console.log(str.match(/\([^)]*\)|[A-Z\d]+/g));
// gives you ["B2B", "(A2C,AMM)", "(BNC,1NF)", "(106,A01)", "AAA", "AX3"]
```

*Java edition:*

```
String str = "B2B,(A2C,AMM),(BNC,1NF),(106,A01),AAA,AX3";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\([^)]*\\)|[A-Z\\d]+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
List<String> matches = new ArrayList<String>();
while(m.find()){
    matches.add(m.group());
}

for (String val : matches) {
    System.out.println(val);
}
```

Comment: `'\([^)]*\)|[^,()]+'` is another alternative that would allow more characters besides capital letters and digits.

Comment: @user650654 Yes, that's true.

Comment: @Evgeni It's console not Console.

Comment: Note using String.split(...) in Java will not give the desired results.

Answer (score 2):

**One simple iteration** will be probably better option then any regex, especially if your data can have parentheses inside parentheses. For example:

```
String data="Some,(data,(that),needs),to (be, splited) by, comma";
StringBuilder buffer=new StringBuilder();
int parenthesesCounter=0;
for (char c:data.toCharArray()){
    if (c=='(') parenthesesCounter++;
    if (c==')') parenthesesCounter--;
    if (c==',' && parenthesesCounter==0){
        //lets do something with this token inside buffer
        System.out.println(buffer);
        //now we need to clear buffer  
        buffer.delete(0, buffer.length());
    }
    else 
        buffer.append(c);
}
//lets not forget about part after last comma
System.out.println(buffer);
```

output

```
Some
(data,(that),needs)
to (be, splited) by
 comma
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
\w{3}(?=,)|(?<=,)\(\w{3},\w{3}\)(?=,)|(?<=,)\w{3}
```

Explanation: There are three parts separated by OR `(|)`

- `\w{3}(?=,)` - matches the 3 any alphanumeric character (including underscore) and does the positive look ahead for comma
- `(?<=,)\(\w{3},\w{3}\)(?=,)` - matches this pattern `(ABC,E4R)` and also does a positive lookahead and look behind for the comma
- `(?<=,)\w{3}` - matches the 3 any alphanumeric character (including underscore) and does the positive look behind for comma