# Split string by all spaces except those in brackets

Tags: java, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Split a String based on regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12756651/split-a-string-based-on-regex)

I've never been a regular expression guru, so I need your help! I have a string like this:

```
String s = "a [b c] d [e f g]";
```

I want to split this string using spaces as delimiters -- but I don't want to split on spaces that appear within the `[]` brackets. So, from the example above, I would like this array:

```
{"a", "[b c]", "d", "[e f g]"}
```

Any advice on what regex could be used in conjunction with `split` in order to achieve this?

---

Here's another example:

```
"[a b] c [[d e] f g]"
```

becomes

```
{"[a b]", "c", "[[d e] f g]"}
```

Comment: [Lesson: Regular Expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/)

Comment: @artbristol Yes they can, I'd like no splitting to happen within any set of brackets. I edited to include another example.

Comment: @A.R.S, then you can't do it with regular expressions.  Time to write a parser.

Comment: this is the third exact duplicate question..[this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12756651/split-a-string-based-on-regex/12756722#12756722) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12305182/parse-commas-not-surrounded-by-brackets/12305883#12305883)

Comment: @CarlNorum you can...check out the above similar question i answered

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think this should work, using [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) - it matches no whitespace that comes before closing bracket without an opening bracket:

```
"a [b c] d [e f g]".split("\\s+(?![^\\[]*\\])");
```

For nested brackets you will need to write a parser, regexes can't afford an infinite level and get too complicated for more than one or two levels. My expression for example fails for

```
"[a b [c d] e] f g"
```

Comment: It doesn't compile - I get "malformed regular expression" error

Comment: Hm, does java need `[` to be escaped inside a character class? Thanks for the hint

Comment: @Jimmy: I just edited in the escaping, before it was `"…[^[]…"`

Comment: @Bergi yes- the corrected version works! +1

Comment: @Bergi Any way to have this work for both `[]` and `{}` brackets (non-nested)? e.g. `a b {c d} [e f]` would become `a, b, {c d}, [e f]`.

Comment: @A.R.S.: Then use `"\\s+(?![^\\[]*\\])(?![^\\{]*\\})"`

Comment: @Bergi how would be the express to split by white space but to ignore spaces in `()` instead of `{}`

Comment: @DanielNascimento Just replace the `\[` and `\]` in the regex by `\(` and `\)` respectively.

Answer (score 3):

You can not do that with single regex, simply because it can not match open/close braces and handle nested braces.

Regexes are not turing-complete, so even if it *might* look as working, there will be the case where it fails to.

So I'd rather suggest to program your own few lines of code which will definitely handle all cases.

You may create very simple grammar for [JavaCC](http://javacc.java.net/) or [AntLR](http://www.antlr.org/) or use simple stack-based parser.

Comment: you can do it in regex..nd it works fine..

Comment: [[xx], [y]] z t [z [x] y]

go ahead.

Comment: did it..2 times [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12756651/split-a-string-based-on-regex/12756722#12756722) and above..

Comment: works in c# but not in java...thxx to java's limited support of lookbehind

Comment: Regexes with look-back/look forward and other perl-inspired stuff has nothing to do with regular expressions themselves. This question related to Java, I don't care much what works with C# or Perl.

Comment: java BUG? Come on. Not implementing strange crutch over regex like is done in Perl is not a reason to call it "bug".

Comment: for me its a bug..c# does it.y not java..

Comment: why do I or TS care about C#? It's Java. C# lacks JDBC/JMS support, its a bug of C#.

Comment: u r getting it all wrong..java supports lookbehind but cant do it properly..thts y i called it a bug..no hard feelings for java..

Comment: please share the BUGID in Oracle issue tracking.

Answer (score 3):

As said in other answers you need a parser for that.
Here a string that fail with previous regex solutions.

```
"[a b] c [a [d e] f g]"
```

EDIT:

```
public static List<String> split(String s){
    List<String> l = new LinkedList<String>();
    int depth=0;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i++){
        char c = s.charAt(i);
        if(c=='['){
            depth++;
        }else if(c==']'){
            depth--;
        }else if(c==' ' && depth==0){
            l.add(sb.toString());
            sb = new StringBuilder();
            continue;
        }
        sb.append(c);
    }
    l.add(sb.toString());

    return l;
}
```

Comment: you can do it in regex..u dont need a parser

Comment: How can you manage multiple nested [] with a regex ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly then may be the answer is following rule4.

```
rule1 -> ((a-z).(\w))*.(a-z)

rule2 -> ([).rule1.(])

rule3 -> ([).(rule1.(\w))*.rule2.((\w).rule1)*.(])

rule4 -> rule1 | rule3
```

Answer (score -1):

**FOR NON NESTED**

```
\\s+(?![^\\[]*\\])
```

**FOR NESTED**([] inside [])

```
(?<!\\[[^\\]]*)\\s+(?![^\\[]*\\])
```

Comment: The compiler complains that there is an invalid escape sequence in the second regex.

Comment: Same thing for the first regex.

Comment: @A.R.S. try removing the escaped  character \

Comment: @Anirudha I managed to get the first regex to work, still having trouble with the second one.

Comment: @Anirudha For the second regex: `java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Look-behind group does not have an obvious maximum length near index 11`

Comment: @A.R.S. it should work..its working in c# regex..i dnt knw y its givin such error

Comment: I guess there are subtle differences between C# and Java in terms of regex.

Comment: @Anirudha: Java lookbehind is very limited

Comment: @Bergi Does that mean a Java equivalent of this regex does not exist?

Comment: @Anirudha Any way to have this work for *both* `[]` and `{}` brackets (non-nested)?