# Don't replace regex if it is enclosed by a character

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I would like to replace all strings that are enclosed by `-` into strings enclosed by `~`, but not if this string again is enclosed by `*`.

As an example, this string...

```
The -quick- *brown -f-ox* jumps.
```

...should become...

```
The ~quick~ *brown -f-ox* jumps.
```

We see `-` is only replaced if it is *not* within `*<here>*`.

My javascript-regex for now (which takes no care whether it is enclosed by `*` or not):

```
var message = source.replace(/-(.[^-]+?)-/g, "~$1~");
```

Edit: Note that it might be the case that there is an odd number of `*`s.

Comment: yup i am amazed, such a good question.

Comment: What when there is odd number of * characters? E.g. `The *-quick-* brown * -f-ox* jumps*.` Which `-` characters should be replaced and why?

Comment: @Maras The last `*` is not replaced. It is printed as `*`

Comment: Firefox's `y` flag, [said to be proposed for ECMAScript 6](http://xregexp.com/flags/) would help a lot: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a tricky sort of thing to do with regular expressions. I think what I'd do is something like this:

```
var msg = source.replace(/(-[^-]+-|\*[^*]+\*)/g, function(_, grp) {
  return grp[0] === '-' ? grp.replace(/^-(.*)-$/, "~$1~") : grp;
});
```

**[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Zb6BU/)**

That looks for *either* `-` or `*` groups, and only performs the replacement on dashed ones. In general, "nesting" syntaxes are challenging (or impossible) with regular expressions. (And of course as a comment on the question notes, there are special cases — dangling metacharacters — that complicate this too.)

Comment: Working example : http://jsfiddle.net/Zb6BU/ - not sure why this isn't getting up votes, this works just as intended! +1

Comment: @Bergi I see that now, +1's for all :) haha

Comment: @Pointy: The group is really unnecessary, it matches what the first argument contains… And you shouldn't use bracket notation on strings.

Comment: @Bergi yes that's probably true; it's just a habit. I don't know what you mean about bracket notation.  Oh - you mean instead of `.charAt()`?  Are there modern browsers that don't do that?

Comment: @Bergi [it's in the spec :-)](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.5.5.2)

Comment: Could you please explain how it would look like if you replace all `:D`, but  not if they're between `-`s?

Comment: @poitroae - hmm, that's a somewhat different problem; I'd have to think about it. You may want to ask a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

I would solve it by splitting the array based on `*` and then replacing only the even indices. Matching unbalanced stars is trickier, it involves knowing whether the last item index is odd or even:

```
'The -quick- *brown -f-ox* jumps.'
    .split('*')
    .map(function(item, index, arr) { 
        if (index % 2) {
            if (index < arr.length - 1) {
                return item; // balanced
            }
            // not balanced
            item = '*' + item;
        }
        return item.replace(/\-([^-]+)\-/, '~$1~');
    })
    .join('');
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/afexud/1/)

Comment: What if the string contains a `*` that isn't part of a pair? e.g. `'The -quick- *brown -f-ox jumps.'` If I understand correctly, in this case both `-quick-` and `-f-` should be replaced, but only the `-quick-` will.

Comment: @KenB It would assume that the stars are well balanced :)

Comment: Depending on context, that's a pretty big assumption.

Comment: Won't you need to `join` the result of `map`?

Comment: @KenB That should be fixed now :)

Answer (score 1):

Finding out whether a match is *not* enclosed by some delimiters is a very complicated task - see also [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12884573/1048572). [Lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) could help, but JS only supports lookahead. So we could rewrite "*not surrounded by `~`*" to "*followed by an even number or `~`*", and match on that:

```
source.replace(/-([^-]+)-(?=[^~]*([^~]*~[^~]*~)*$)/g, "~$1~");
```

But better we match on both `-` and `*`, so that we consume anything wrapped in `*`s as well and can then decide in a callback function not to replace it:

```
source.replace(/-([^-]+)-|\*([^*]+)\*/g, function(m, hyp) {
    if (hyp) // the first group has matched
        return "~"+hyp+"~";
    // else let the match be unchanged:
    return m;
});
```

This has the advantage of being able to better specify "*enclosed*", e.g. by adding word boundaries on the "inside", for better handling of invalid patterns (odd number of * characters as mentioned by @Maras for example) - the current regex just takes the next two appearances.

Answer (score 0):

A terser version of Jack's very clear answer.

```
source.split(/(\*[^*]*\*)/g).map(function(x,i){
return i%2?x:x.replace(/-/g,'~');
}).join('');
```

Seems to work,
Cheers.