# regex match space not in parenthesis, accolades or squared barackets

Tags: regex

I'm trying to split a sentence by whitespace/space but I must exclude space located inside parenthesis `()`, accolades `{}` or squared brackets `[]`.

ex string: `[apples carrots] (car plane train) {food water} foo bar` should result in an array containing:

- [apples carrots]
- (car plane train)
- {food water}
- foo
- bar

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Split string by all spaces except those in brackets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12884573/split-string-by-all-spaces-except-those-in-brackets)

Comment: Do you forsee nested punctuation (balanced). If true, there can be solutions for that as well. Just a FYI ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Split on whitespace followed by a positive look-ahead that checks if next bracket char (if any) is an open one (or end of input):

```
\s+(?=[^\])}]*([\[({]|$))
```

Comment: You might be missing a closing parenthesis.  `\s+(  <-- Unbalanced  '(' ?=[^\])}]*([\[({]|$)`

Comment: @sln quite so. Fixed. Thx. (I typed it in on my iPhone - can be hard to pick up stuff like that)

Comment: @Bohemian, this was not really working for me: it is missing some blank spaces which are not in parenthesis

Comment: @francoisromain what was your input exactly, and what do you expect from the match?

Comment: @Bohemian input: `'#666 white'`. output: `['#666', '', 'white']`, where it should be: `['#666', 'white']`. (there is an extra empty string in the middle)

Comment: @fran show me the whole code, like `"the exact string you're using".split("the exact regex you're using")`

Comment: @Bohemian just copy your regex above: `var t = '#666 white'; var r = t.split(/\s+(?=[^\])}]*([\[({]|$))/); console.log(r);`

Comment: I'm really appreciate your answer. But I have a further problem that is I have a recurive brackets and this regex capture space between '[' (left brackets). Would you have any help? text is `[[    []]]` How can I prevent regex to capture any space outside most outter brackets.

Comment: @Natt I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17986078/256196) will do what you want if modify it to use square brackets

Comment: @Bohemian I have tried your suggestion but it still not work, that regex still match text in bracket. Could it be that there are nested bracket? https://imgur.com/a/U4Je4

Comment: @natt That other answer will work with nested brackets. What is the input that it isn't working for? Even better, post a new question with your best effort at a regex so far and the input it's not working with and details of *how* it's not working and how you want it to work.

Answer (score 5):

Not splitting, but matching and trimming. Example is in JavaScript, you can try it out in browser console:

```
var a = '[apples carrots] (car plane train) {food water} foo bar';
a.match(/[a-zA-Z0-9\[\]\(\){}]+/g).map(function (s) { return s.replace(/[\[\]\(\)\{\}]/, ''); });
["apples", "carrots", "car", "plane", "train", "food", "water", "foo", "bar"]
```

Alternatively:

```
a.split(/\s+(?![^\[]*\]|[^(]*\)|[^\{]*})/)
```

Produces:

```
["[apples carrots]", "(car plane train)", "{food water}", "foo", "bar"]
```

Answer (score 0):

to match the space outside (), {} and [] use this pattern `(\s)(?:(?=(?:(?![\]\)}]).)*[\[\({])|(?!.*[\]\)}]))` [Demo](http://regex101.com/r/aH2oO3)