# python: split a list of strings based on a condition

Tags: python, string, list, split

I have a list like the following:

```
my_list =['[] [How, you, today] [] []','[] [the] [weather, nice, though] [] []']
```

I would like to split the list in a way to get the following output.

```
output_list = ['[]', '[How, you, today]', '[]', '[]','[]', '[the]',
      '[weather, nice, though]', '[]', '[]']
```

I have tried the following but do not get the result i am looking for.

```
[word for line in my_list for word in line.split('')]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost. First of all, the following produces what you want -

```
[('[' + word) if i else word for line in my_list for i, word in enumerate(line.split(' ['))]
```

More specifically, it seems you want to split by a space-character, but only if it's the beginning of a new list of words. Hence splitting with `' ['`.
Next up you'll be missing the opening bracket for each list except the first. So by "manually" adding it on for all except the first (by using an enumeration index), you get the requested output.

Comment: hi, thank you for your reply. Unfortunately this is the output i get : ['[]', '[How,', 'you,', 'today]', '[]', '[]', '[]', '[the]', '[weather,', 'nice,', 'though]', '[]', '[]'].

Comment: That looks *exactly* like the output you requested in your post. If not please point out where it differs?

Comment: instead of '[How,', 'you,', 'today]' I would like '[How, you, today]' for where the list is not empty

Comment: Got it. FTFY ;-)

Answer (score 2):

This link is for java, but the regular expression is the same: [Split string by all spaces except those in brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12884573/split-string-by-all-spaces-except-those-in-brackets)

split by regex in python (add import re to your script):

```
rx = '\\s+(?![^\\[]*\\])'

# join strings into one string, then split back to list from there
output_list = re.split(rx, ' '.join(my_list))

# ['[]', '[How, you, today]', '[]', '[]', '[]', '[the]', '[weather, nice, though]', '[]', '[]']
```