# Split string by comma but ignore commas in brackets or in quotes

Tags: java, regex, string, csv, split

I have a string like `hello, "darkness, my", (old, friend)` and I want this splitted result:
`hello`
`"darkness, my"`
`(old, friend)`

I found a way to ignore the commas in "-marks (`,?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$`) and another way to ignore the commas in brackets (`,(?=[^\\)]*(?:\\(|$))`).
When I use the first, I get:
`hello`
`"darkness, my"`
`(old`
`friend)`
And when I use the second, I get:
`hello`
`"darkness`
`my"`
`(old, friend)`

But how do I combine these two solutions?

Comment: Variation of [**The best regex trick ever**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html) - scroll down to the `Java` section.

Comment: You can always use both tests... `,(?=...)(?=...)`. Or to make your life simpler don't use split which describes delimiters, use `Matcher#find` and describe tokens which you are interested in `any words` OR `"text between quotes"` OR `(text between parenthesis)`. Or maybe even better don't use regex at all. Simply iterate over characters and pay attention to comma which is outside of parenthesis or quotes like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12756651/split-a-string-based-on-regex/12756948#12756948

Comment: Thanks both of you. It is for a very small thing so I just used both tests as @Pshemo suggested and it worked

Comment: did you get right answer?

Comment: @payamsbr I think so. It did not raise any exceptions and the data looks ok. I need to double check some of the data to be sure. Do you think that it should not work because of a mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably easier to match the parts, rather than splitting them.

[`\s*("[^"]*"|\([^)]*\)|[^,]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/d9i1T6/)

This will capture each piece of data as group 1.

Comment: thanks that worked. The other solution was to use both tests `,(?=...)(?=...)` as @Pshemo suggested but this is approach also works. Thanks